# app crashing on higher OS versions, but not on lower versions

Tags: android

I developed as simple android application that logs in and then posts statistics information to the database. The problem is when I install it on my phone which runs on android version 4 it works fine but when I run it on phones which are android version 6 and above it crashes. can someone assist me on what the problem could be

Comment: post  your logcat

Comment: so where is the error message?

Comment: post your code please ..

Comment: thanks let me post the code

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like permissions problem. Since android 6 android apps are requires to ask permissions at runtime and not just at installation time. See docs reference below
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview